# Session not Being Abandoned - Using Menu ControL?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, authentication, menu

I have a Menu control to which I've added a Logout menu item. The code looks like so:

```
Protected Sub Menu1_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles Menu1.MenuItemClick
    If e.Item.Value = "Logout" Then
        Session.Abandon()
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

When I logout it redirects fine, but it doesn't seem to be abandoning the session. I've successfully implemented logout in another application by using a LinkButton, this seems to be an issue specifically with the Menu control?

Comment: where do you know, the session is not abandoned? Maybe it is a new session which you see?

Comment: B/c when the session has been abandoned the menu isn't supposed to be visible, but it is still visible...and I can still access all the pages from the previous session that are locked out if you aren't authenticated.

Comment: One way you can do this, pass something in query string and then abondon the session to login page application as well.

Comment: Any of the answers solves your problem! .. waiting your feedback =)

Answer (score 1):

Logically its not possible but It seems that after a session is abandoned and before going to login.aspx page, your session starts again somewhere. Specially check in your master page load.

Comment: It possibly starts by loading the login.aspx page.

Comment: I suppose that is possible user - but I doubt it, b/c I load the login.aspx page in the other app. and don't have this problem.

Comment: that's the reason, session.abondon only abondon the sessions to only the current session. Since the login page is of other application, session remains.

Comment: One way you can do this, pass something in query string and then abondon the session to login page application as well.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similar topic about your problem .. so I think it might help.

This will be your code

```
Protected Sub Menu1_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles Menu1.MenuItemClick
    If e.Item.Value = "Logout" Then
        Session.Abandon()
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage("action=logout")
    End If
End Sub
```

Another and more clean solution:

> set
>   LoginStatus control's property logout
>   action to RedirectToLoginPage, login
>   status control will automatically log
>   user out clearing login status and
>   cookies if used on client machine.

......I think the first solution will be better for you, since you're using a MenuControl and need something tailored or costumed to fit in. But you are the one who can see how the whole application works, so you are the one to decide.

Source article from the asp.net forums: ["Session.Abandon/LoginStatus Logout creating loop?"](http://forums.asp.net/t/1563304.aspx/1?Session%20Abandon%20LoginStatus%20Logout%20creating%20loop%20)

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced, you are facing a session related problem. Could be an authentication problem as well. I would expect SessionAbondon() to work the way it should. Note, that 'session' and 'authentication' are completely different things. They use a different cookie as well.

In order to track down the problem, I suggest to

- monitor (trace) your cookie transfer for every request (most simple with firebug extension for firefox or by using the Trace feature of ASP.NET)
- store a uniquely identifyable string into the session right before Session.Abandon() and debug into the login page code behind, to see, if it is still there
- if nothing helps, post more code here